# Error Deploying to Elastic Beanstalk using Rails/puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, assets, puma

```
[Instance: i-dc5e265b] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1
Output: (TRUNCATED)...s/lib/less/import-visitor.js:34:22) at Parser.parser.parse (/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/less-2.6.0/lib/less/js/lib/less/parser.js:675:22) 
Unrecognised input Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile (See full trace by running task with --trace). 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/11_asset_compilation.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

It's my first time deploying to EB and I can't seem to find any answers online. Something about my assets is causing errors. I've tried precompiling assets before deploying without any luck.

Comment: Look into `/var/log/eb-activity.log`. What does it say there?

Comment: @Uzbekjon Ah, I figured it out by looking at the logs. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by using the elastic beanstalk logger with the command:

```
eb logs
```

There were errors in my bootstrap css that was causing the deployment to fail.